# PhantomJS can not be used in scrapy with SSR

Tags: python, scrapy

I am running win10 system,My python version is 3.6, scrapy version is 1.5, when I use the SSR client to open the global agent, it will give an error, but when I turn off SSR will be normal, which is why?

And in my proxy for phantomjs SSR proxy 127.0.0.1:1083 port will also be given an error, the main error is inside the webdrive.py file, and twisted

spider.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from uu134.items import Uu134Item
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class DowmloadSpider(CrawlSpider):
     name = 'dowmload'
     allowed_domains = ['www.134uu.com']
     start_urls = ['https://www.134uu.com/htm/vodlist3/1.htm']

link_extractor = {
    'one_lever_link': LinkExtractor(allow=r'/htm/vodlist3/\d+.htm'),
    'two_lever_link': LinkExtractor(allow=r'/htm/vod3/\d+.htm'),
    # 'content': LinkExtractor(allow='bbscon,board,\w+,file,M\.\d+\.A\.html$'),
}

def parse(self, response):
    for link in self.link_extractor['one_lever_link'].extract_links(response):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=link.url, callback=self.parse_page)

def parse_page(self, response):
    for link in self.link_extractor['two_lever_link'].extract_links(response):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=link.url, callback=self.parse_page)

def parse_handle(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

middlewares.py

```
class JSPageMiddleware(object):
def __init__(self):
    ua = random.choice(self.user_agent_list) # 随机选择一个User-Agent
    dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)  # 导入PhantomJS的设置
    dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (ua)  # 设置PhantomJS的随机User-Agent
    dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.loadImages"] = False  # 禁止加载图片
    dcap['proxy'] = '127.0.0.1:1083'

    self.browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='D:/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs.exe', desired_capabilities=dcap, port=
                                       1083)
    super(JSPageMiddleware, self).__init__()

# 通过 PhantomJS 请求动态网页，代替scrapy的downloader
def process_request(self, request, spider):

    self.browser.get(request.url)
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    print("访问:{0}".format(request.url))

    # 直接返回给spider，而非再传给downloader
    return HtmlResponse(url=self.browser.current_url, body=self.browser.page_source, encoding="utf-8",
                        request=request)
```

error info:

```
2018-02-03 16:25:54 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: uu134)
2018-02-03 16:25:54 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.1.1.0, libxml2 2.9.7, cssselect 1.0.1, parsel 1.3.1, w3lib 1.18.0, Twisted 17.9.0, Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)], pyOpenSSL 17.5.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017), cryptography 2.1.4, Platform Windows-10-10.0.15063-SP0
2018-02-03 16:25:54 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'uu134', 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False, 'LOG_FILE': 'Spider.log', 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'uu134.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['uu134.spiders']}
2018-02-03 16:25:54 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-02-03 16:25:55 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2018-02-03 16:25:55 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
result = g.send(result)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 80, in crawl
self.engine = self._create_engine()
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 105, in _create_engine
return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 69, in __init__
self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\__init__.py", line 88, in __init__
self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 40, in from_settings
mw = mwcls()
File "E:\xampp\htdocs\study_spider\uu134\uu134\middlewares.py", line 173, in __init__1083)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 87, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 141, in start_session
'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 151, in check_response
raise exception_class(value)
```